# Getting SimpleXMLElement to include the encoding in output

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

This:

```
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement("<foo />");
echo($XML->asXML());
```

...outputs this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo/>
```

But I want it to output the encoding, too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo/>
```

Is there some way to tell SimpleXMLElement to include the encoding attribute of the <?xml?> tag? Aside from doing this:

```
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><foo />");
echo($XML->asXML());
```

Which works, but it's annoying to have to manually specify the version and encoding.

Assume for the purposes of this question that I cannot use DOMDocument instead.

Comment: Why do you need the encoding present in the output?

Comment: Because that's an external requirement. :)

Answer (score 24):

You can try this, but you must use **simplexml_load_string** for $xml

```
$xml // Your main SimpleXMLElement
$xml->addAttribute('encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

Or you can still use other means to add the encoding to your output.

**Simple Replacement**

```
$outputXML=str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', $outputXML);
```

**Regular Expressions**

```
$outputXML=preg_replace('/<\?\s*xml([^\s]*)\?>/' '<?xml $1 encoding="UTF-8"?>', $outputXML);
```

**DOMDocument** - *I know you said you don't want to use DOMDocument, but here is an example*

```
$xml = dom_import_simplexml($simpleXML);
$xml->xmlEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$outputXML = $xml->saveXML();
```

You can wrap this code into a function that receives a parameter $encoding and adds it to the

Comment: There is a syntax error in your **DOMDocument**: `$xml->xmlEndoding='UTF-8';` should be `$xml->xmlEncoding='UTF-8';`.

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev I corrected the typo in the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Simple and clear only do this

```
$XMLRoot = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><element></element>');
```

OutPut

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <element></element>
```

to add attributes in element only use

```
$XMLRoot->addAttribute('name','juan');
```

to add child use

```
$childElement = $XMLRoot->addChild('elementChild');
$childElement->addAttribute('attribName','somthing');
```

Comment: clear & easy! Thx. one hint: `$XMLRoot = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><element />');` to make it even shorter

Comment: +1 This also works with `$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ... rest of your xml ...`. Comparing XML created in this manner, and with `Header('Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'); echo $xml->asXML();`, there are no noticeable differences.

Answer (score 4):

The DOMDoc proposal of [Cristian Toma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206090) seems a good approach if the document isn't too heavy. You could wrap it up in something like this:

```
private function changeEncoding(string $xml, string $encoding) {
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $dom->encoding = $encoding;
    return $dom->saveXML();
}
```

Comes in useful when you don't have access to the serializer producing the xml.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you will need to do this on creation of each XML object.  Even if SimpleXMLElement had a way of setting it you would still need to set it as I guess it would be possible for the object to pick a valid default.

Maybe create a constant and Create objects like this

```
$XML = new SimpleXMLElement($XMLNamespace . "<foo />");
echo($XML->asXML());
```

Comment: Easiest solution ever, just make sure to add "\n" after $XMLNamespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an encoding, SimpleXML cannot (sanely) guess which one you intended.

Comment: I know, but the only way to specify an encoding for SimpleXML is to make it explicit in the constructor -- and then you have to specify the XML version attribute too, or it throws an error.  I can obviously do it that way, it's just annoying to have to do it at all.

I guess SimpleXML is a little too simple :)

Comment: I can't find any reference to this in the documentation but I have the impression that you *can't* specify an encoding—because SimpleXML expects UTF-8.