# Include XML encoding in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am a beginner in PHP and XML.

Can somebody tell me how to include XML encoding when I write a new xml file.

Here are the codes:

**`writexml.php`**

```
<?php 
 $ids =  array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
 $names = array("Jean Claude Van Damme", "Scott Adkins", "Dolph Ludgren", "Michael Jai White", "Michael Worth");

 $domdoc = new DOMDocument(); 
 $domdoc->formatOutput = true; 

 $el_actionstars = $domdoc->createElement( "actionstars" ); 
 $domdoc->appendChild( $el_actionstars  ); 

 $arr_size = count($ids);

 for ($i=0; $i < $arr_size; $i++) {
  $el_actionstar = $domdoc->createElement( "actionstar" ); 

  $el_id =  $domdoc->createElement( "id" ); 
  $el_id->appendChild( $domdoc->createTextNode($ids[$i] . "")); 
  $el_actionstar->appendChild($el_id);

  $el_name =  $domdoc->createElement( "name" ); 
  $el_name->appendChild( $domdoc->createTextNode($names[$i] . "")); 
  $el_actionstar->appendChild($el_name);


  $el_actionstars->appendChild($el_actionstar);
 }

 echo $domdoc->saveXML(); 
 $domdoc->save("actionstars.xml") 
?>
```

The xml output is `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and I want to add the encoding to make it look like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`. Pls help...

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869650/getting-simplexmlelement-to-include-the-encoding-in-output)

Comment: The example for [DOMDocument::__construct](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php) shows how to do that. Please refer to the manual before asking questions with obvious answers.

Comment: Lol. Someone inject more love...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See bottom of http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

> When you save whole document:
>   DOMDocument->saveXML() produces string
>   in encoding defined in property
>   DOMDocument->encoding.
>
> When you save only one node:
>   DOMDocument->saveXML(DOMNode) produces
>   always string in UTF-8.

You can set it in the constructor

```
DOMDocument::__construct ([ string $version [, string $encoding ]] )
```

e.g.,

```
$domdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: Do you mean whenever I'll save a whole document I have to check the DOMDocument->encoding?

Comment: Just create the domdoc with the encoding you want.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this in your instantiation:

```
/**
 * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 */
$domdoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

As seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

Try with `new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`