# How to add attribute to xml header using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting SimpleXMLElement to include the encoding in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869650/getting-simplexmlelement-to-include-the-encoding-in-output)

**PHP :**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<Title0></Title0>");
$xml->Title1='Some Text  1';
$output = $xml->asXML('mak.xml');
```

**XML Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<Title0>
    <Title1>Some Text 1</Title1>
</Title0>
```

But I want to add attrbute like `encoding="utf-8"` to xml header , so that I can have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<Title0>
    <Title1>Some Text 1</Title1>
</Title0>
```

I dont want to use find and replace sort of things on the output file.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869650/getting-simplexmlelement-to-include-the-encoding-in-output) might help.

Answer (score -3):

Read this:--

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

try this:-

Example #10 Adding elements and attributes

```
<?php
include 'example.php';
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

$character = $movies->movie[0]->characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movies->movie[0]->addChild('rating', 'PG');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'mpaa');

echo $movies->asXML();
?>
```